# Compiling QScintilla on Ubuntu Fails

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qscintilla

I'm trying to compile Qscintilla 2.9.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit using Qt 5.7 got the following error message:

```
-L/home/mwambi/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib -lQt5PrintSupport -L/usr/lib64 -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lpthread -lGL  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:979: recipe for target 'libqscintilla2.so.12.0.1' failed
make: *** [libqscintilla2.so.12.0.1] Error 1
```

I do not know what the library GL is and where to find it. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, this troubleshooting procedure is enough to solve about 90% of missing library issues during compilation:

1. "-l[name]" implies there's a "lib[name].so"
2. Search your system for "lib[name]" (use locate or find).

   If you find it on your system, check paths ($LB_LIBRARY_PATH and the build system's -L flags) and verify that the architecture matches (x86+64 vs. i686).
3. Do a repository search for "lib[name]" (use apt, yum, synaptic, &c.).

   Install it if it's missing.
4. Type "lib[name].so" into google or a dedicated package-search site (like RPMFind or packages.ubuntu.com) and see what package names come up, then search for as in #2-3.

In this case, libGL is an implementation of OpenGL. You can install Mesa or find an alternative implementation (I've only ever used Qt with Mesa). [Here's a list of packages that provide libGL](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libGL.so); if you already have one of these installed on your system, try fetching the dev versions of whichever ones you already have.